# Search for motifs with degenerate positions

Tags: python, sequence, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a 15-mer nucleotide motif that uses degenerate nucleotide sequences. Example: ATNTTRTCNGGHGCN.

I would search a set of sequences for the occurrence of this motif. However, my other sequences are exact sequences, i.e. they have no ambiguity.

I have tried doing a `for` loop within the sequences to search for this, but I have not been able to do non-exact searches. The code I use is modeled after the code on the [Biopython cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html).

```
for pos,seq in m.instances.search(test_seq):
    print pos, seq
```

I would like to search for all possible exact instances of the non-exact 15-mer. Is there a function available, or would I have to resort to defining my own function for that? (I'm okay doing the latter, just wanted to triple-check with the world that I'm not duplicating someone else's efforts before I go ahead - I have already browsed through what I thought was the relevant parts of the docs.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Biopython's [`nt_search`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils-pysrc.html#nt_search). It looks for a subsequence in a DNA sequence, expanding ambiguity codes to the possible nucleotides in that position. Example:

```
>>> from Bio import SeqUtils
>>> pat = "ATNTTRTCNGGHGCN"
>>> SeqUtils.nt_search("CCCCCCCATCTTGTCAGGCGCTCCCCCC", pat)
['AT[GATC]TT[AG]TC[GATC]GG[ACT]GC[GATC]', 7]
```

It returns a list where the first item is the search pattern, followed by the positions of the matches.