# Can Biopython perform Seq.find() accounting for ambiguity codes

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to be able to search a Seq object for a subsequnce Seq object accounting for ambiguity codes. For example, the following should be true:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet.IUPAC import IUPACAmbiguousDNA

amb = IUPACAmbiguousDNA()
s1 = Seq("GGAAAAGG", amb)
s2 = Seq("ARAA", amb)     # R = A or G
print s1.find(s2)
```

If ambiguity codes were taken into account, the answer should be

```
>>> 2
```

But the answer i get is that no match is found, or

```
>>> -1
```

Looking at the biopython source code, it doesnt appear that ambiguity codes are taken into account, as the subseqeunce is converted to a string using the private _get_seq_str_and_check_alphabet method, then the built in string method find() is used. Of course if this is the case, the "R" ambiguity code will be taken as a literal "R", not an A or G.

I could figure out how to do this with a home made method, but it seems like something that should be taken care of in the biopython packages using its Seq objects. Is there something I am missing here.

Is there a way to search for sub sequence membership accounting for ambiguity codes?

Comment: Maybe also ask your question at [BioStars](https://www.biostars.org/) or file a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for motifs with degenerate positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522093/search-for-motifs-with-degenerate-positions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can read from the documentation for `Seq.find` here:

http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Seq.Seq-class.html#find

It appears that this method works similar to the `str.find` method in that it looks for **exact** match. So, while the dna sequence can contain ambiguity codes, the `Seq.find()` method will only return a match when the **exact** subsequence matches.

To do what you want maybe the `ntsearch` function will work:

[Search for motifs with degenerate positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522093/search-for-motifs-with-degenerate-positions)

Comment: Great this does the job. I figured Biopython must have taken this into account somehwere. Interestingly, the nt_search takes 2 strings as arguments, not Seq objects.